# Rails has_many sums and counts with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've got a dilemma I think I may have coded myself into a corner over. Here's the setup.

My site has users. Each user has a collection of stories that they post. And each story has a collection of comments from other users.

I want to display on the User's page, a count of the total number of comments from other users.

So a User has_many Stories, and a Story has_many comments.

What I tried was loading all the users stories in @stories and then displaying @stories.comments.count, but I get undefined method 'comments' when I try to do that. Is there an efficient ActiveRecord way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick solution is to iterate over the @stories collection and add the counts up.  This is not a purely active record solution though.

```
totalComments = 0
@stories.each do |story|
    totalComments += story.count
end
```

For a pure active record solution I would need to assume that each has_many association has a corresponding belongs_to association.  So a User has_many Stories and a Story belongs_to a User.  If that is the case and comments have a similar association to stories then you can search comments by user_id. Something like:

```
Comments.where("comment.story.user" => "userId")
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stories
  has_many :comments, through: :stories
end

class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :story
end
```

Now you should be able to get `User.last.comments.count`

I think you need to refine this more for a proper labelling.

Comment: This is a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you should have something like this (note the use of `includes`):

```
@user = User.find( params[:id] )
@stories = @user.stories.includes(:comments)
```

Then in your view you can do something like the following to show the total number of comments for that particular user:

```
Total number of comments: <%= @stories.map{|story| story.comments.length}.sum %>
```